# Empty Space Around Google Map Marker Icons In Chrome Device Mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-devtools, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to use an svg file as my marker icons. Everything looks great, except for that fact that there is this giant empty space around the marker, rendering them incredibly hard to interact with when grouped up. I've tried using icon.size and icon.scaledSize to address my issue but I still can't remove the empty space. Perhaps it's my svg file?

```
  function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: {
        url: 'assets/icons/art.svg'
    }
  });
}
```

[this is the svg (converted to png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgXvD.png)
[The actual svg in question](https://svgur.com/s/8P9)

[Here's the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyVFg.png)

**EDIT:**

It turned out that using Chrome's [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) was interfering with the way Maps rendered the icons.

I ended up seeing the expected result after following @bonnie suggestion (cropped any excess empty space from my files), adjusting the `icon.scale` and `icon.scaledSize` properties, and exiting Device Mode.

The final icon object was:

```
icon = {
    url: 'assets/icons/art.svg',
    size: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
};
```

Google maps rendered
`icon.size` as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQWLc.jpg)
& `icon.scaledSize` as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxm3t.jpg)

I still have no idea why Chrome's Device Mode can't render marker icons properly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (we need the .svg)

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for your response, I've added a link the .svg I'm trying to work with. Is there anything else I may provide to help people test?

Answer (score 0):

The viewbox of the SVG is too large. If you open in a graphics program, such as Illustrator, you can adjust the size of the artboard, so that it has no blank space around the edge of the graphic.

Comment: I've checked using photoshop that there's almost no whitespace around the icon. If you check out https://svgur.com/s/8P9 it shows that the whitespace around is not nearly has much as what google maps is rendering. I haven't tried scaling it down yet, so I'll give that a shot. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Have you zoomed in or out of the map when it does that, or does it also do it on initial load of the map?

Comment: After scaling the image, this is the result: https://i.imgur.com/wc9TwYr.png

I'm concerned that there isn't a way to configure google maps marker icon dimensions.

Comment: It adds the space around on the initial load. I need to zoom quite far to be able to select markers that are grouped. This could also just be how people interact with maps and I'm being too particular? Another thought is that I'm using chrome's responsive web inspector, so that could be causing issues.

Comment: thanks for your help, after disabling Device Mode and cropping all empty space, I am now seeing the expected result. I've updated the question to address why Device Mode doesn't render Icons Properly.

Comment: @JayJackson if you are happy with the solution, you can answer your own question below.